# Subtract two times

Tags: php

I have a large form, but some of it works in mysterious ways.
The below works fine at first glance, two times are subtracted and the correct value is displayed, BUT the value that is sent to the database is the PREVIOUS entry.

I can't figure out, why I get 2 different results in 1 entry!

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        include "DBConnect.php";

        $dag = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_POST['dag']);
        $dato = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_POST['dato']);
        $helligdag = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_POST['helligdag']);
        $plads = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_POST['plads']);
        $frihed = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_POST['frihed']);
        $moedetid = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_POST['moedetid']);
        $fyraften = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_POST['fyraften']);
        $timer = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_POST['timer']);
        $timer50 = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_POST['timer50']);
        $timer100 = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_POST['timer100']);

        mysqli_query($dbcon, "INSERT INTO content
            (dag, dato, helligdag, plads, frihed, moedetid, fyraften, timer, timer50, timer100)
            VALUES ('$dag', '$dato', '$helligdag', '$plads', '$frihed', '$moedetid', '$fyraften', '$timer', '$timer50', '$timer100')");
    }
?>

<?php 
        $timer = '';
        $moedetid = $_POST['moedetid'];
        $fyraften = $_POST['fyraften'];
        $t1 = strtotime($moedetid);
        $t2 = strtotime($fyraften);
        $timer = abs($t2 - $t1) / 3600;
        $timer = intval($timer) . ':' . (($timer - intval($timer)) * 60);
?>

<input type="text" name="timer" value="<?php echo $timer; ?>">
```

Comment: How exactly is the subtraction related to your INSERT statement? As far as I can see from your code, you're not doing any calculation before inserting.

Comment: $timer = abs($t2 - $t1) / 3600;
This is the calculation.

Comment: But you're doing that *after* the INSERT, right? Otherwise, how are these two blocks you posted related?

Comment: I did just now create a new table in a different database, so now it works.